# Android - Dynamically changed Layout margins are reset when calling any setImage method on any image from current activity

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have a custom layout (swipableLayout). I change its margins dynamically on MotionEvents. When I set any ImageView or any ImageButton with any setImage method (Bitmap, Drawable, Resource) from current activity at any time, dynamically managed margins are resetted to their initial values. 
I assume it is something internal with setImageXXX  that affects in some way all layouts.

I can`t find any related issue on internet.

**A gif showing the issue:**

http://giphy.com/gifs/rething-xTiN0BFP4kOzh76944

**XML code:**

Also tested with regular ImageViews

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.59"
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/image_edge_up">

                <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                    android:src="@drawable/preload_anim"

                    android:background="@drawable/image_edge_up"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:text="Name, age [gender] - breed   "
                    android:id="@+id/textView13"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="bottom|left"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:text="Park /zone, City"
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/image_edge_up"
                    android:backgroundTintMode="src_atop"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp" />


            </LinearLayout>


            <com.mindfunk.rething.utils.swipableLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.59"
                android:id="@+id/swipableLayout"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/image_edge_up"
                android:visibility="visible">
                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp">

                    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="300dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageView8"


                        android:src="@drawable/preload_anim"
                        android:background="@drawable/image_edge_up"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/cross"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:src="@drawable/cross"
                        android:tint="#ff0000"
                        android:alpha="0" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/tick"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:src="@drawable/tick"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:alpha="0"
                        android:tint="#00bb09" />

                </FrameLayout>


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:text="Name, age [gender]"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="bottom|left"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:typeface="normal" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:text="Park /zone, City"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:background="@drawable/image_edge_up"
                    android:backgroundTintMode="src_atop"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:typeface="normal"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

            </com.mindfunk.rething.utils.swipableLayout>




        </RelativeLayout>
```

**My swipable layout:**

```
public  class swipableLayout extends LinearLayout {

private boolean swiping = false;

public static float   lastTouchx =0;
public static float   lastTouchy =0;
public static float   lastPosx =0;
public static float   lastPosy =0;
private float   initialTouchx =0;
private float   initialTouchy =0;
private int   initialPositionx=0;
private int   initialPositiony=0;
private int height;
private int width;

public swipableLayout(Context context){

    super(context);
}

public swipableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}

public swipableLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

}



@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev);



    switch(action){

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
            final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(ev);

            lastTouchx = ev.getRawX();
            lastTouchy = ev.getRawY();
            initialTouchx = lastTouchx;
            initialTouchy = lastTouchy;


            Log.d("SwipableLayout", "MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN");
            LinearLayout swipableLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipableLayout);
            height = swipableLayout.getHeight();
            width = swipableLayout.getWidth();

            initialPositionx = swipableLayout.getLeft();
            initialPositiony = swipableLayout.getTop();




            break;

        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{

            final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(ev);

            LinearLayout swipableLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipableLayout);

            final float diffX = lastTouchx - ev.getRawX();;
            final float diffY = lastTouchy - ev.getRawY();;
           /* final float diffX = lastTouchx - MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, pointerIndex);
            final float diffY = lastTouchy - MotionEventCompat.getY(ev, pointerIndex);*/
           Log.d("layoutInfo", "["
                    +String.valueOf(swipableLayout.getTop())+","
                    +String.valueOf(swipableLayout.getLeft())+","
                    +String.valueOf(swipableLayout.getBottom())+","
                    +String.valueOf(swipableLayout.getRight())+"]"

            );

            lastTouchx = swipableLayout.getLeft();
            lastTouchy = swipableLayout.getTop();

            lastTouchx = ev.getRawX();
            lastTouchy = ev.getRawY();

            float correction = (swipableLayout.getLeft() + swipableLayout.getRight())/2  - width/2f;

            if(correction>0){

                swipeActivity.setTickAlpha(correction/width);



            }
            else swipeActivity.setCrossAlpha(-correction/width);


          /*  Log.d("correction/width/touchx", String.valueOf(lastTouchx));
            Log.d("correction/width/width", String.valueOf(width));
            Log.d("correction/width/2f", String.valueOf(correction));*/


            int newPosx = Math.round ((swipableLayout.getLeft() - (int) diffX));
            int newPosy = Math.round ((swipableLayout.getTop() - (int) diffY));

            swipableLayout.setLeft(newPosx);
            swipableLayout.setTop(newPosy);
            swipableLayout.setRight(newPosx+width);
            swipableLayout.setBottom(newPosy+height);
            swipableLayout.setRotation(swipableLayout.getLeft()/20);


            break;


        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{

            swipeActivity.setCrossAlpha(0.0f);
            swipeActivity.setTickAlpha(0.0f);

            Log.d("SwipableLayout", "MotionEvent.ACTION_UP");

            if(Math.abs(initialTouchx - lastTouchx) > 0){// swipe
            LinearLayout swipableLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipableLayout);

            swipableLayout.setLeft(initialPositionx);
            swipableLayout.setRight(initialPositionx + width);
            swipableLayout.setTop(initialPositiony);
                swipableLayout.setBottom(initialPositiony+height);

            if(Math.abs(swipableLayout.getRotation()) >18)
            swipeActivity.instance.moveProfiles();


                swipableLayout.setRotation(0.0f);
            }
            else { // click
                swipeActivity.gotoPetViewer();
            }

            break;

        }
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

**My asyncTask:**

```
  private  class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {

        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

// HERE IS THE ISSUE!
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result); //<- WHEN I SET THIS BITMAP, THE UPPER
//swipableLayout goes to the initial position

        imageView9.setTag("adios");
    }
}
```

Delaying Log.d 100 ms after image is loaded  prints the actual information. Layout is returning to initial position,

```
02-21 12:02:56.900 809-809/com.mindfunk.rething D/layoutInfo: [45,418,1016,1098]
02-21 12:02:56.950 809-809/com.mindfunk.rething D/layoutInfo: [45,419,1016,1099]
02-21 12:02:56.984 809-809/com.mindfunk.rething D/layoutInfo: [45,419,1016,1099]
02-21 12:02:57.084 809-809/com.mindfunk.rething D/layoutInfo: [45,421,1016,1101]
02-21 12:02:57.569 809-809/com.mindfunk.rething D/layoutInfo: [45,422,1016,1102]
02-21 12:02:57.936 809-809/com.mindfunk.rething D/layoutInfo: [45,423,1016,1103]
02-21 12:02:58.077 809-809/com.mindfunk.rething D/ServerRequest: http://RETHING/PHP/getThing.php
02-21 12:02:58.077 809-809/com.mindfunk.rething D/ServerRequest:  Params: IDThing=2
02-21 12:02:58.873 809-809/com.mindfunk.rething V/AsyncHttpRH: Progress 397 from 397 (100%)
02-21 12:02:58.888 809-809/com.mindfunk.rething D/ServerRequest: Success: {"res":"1","msg":"ThingProfile2 decargado correctamente","data":{"IDPet":null,"IDUsuario":"29","AliasThing":"ok3","PrecioThing":null,"Localizacion":"Barcelona","Descripcion":"nose","Foto1":"7f1de29e6da19d22b51c68001e7e0e54","Foto2":"a8baa56554f96369ab93e4f3bb068c22","Foto3":"903ce9225fca3e988c2af215d4e544d3","Foto4":"0a09c8844ba8f0936c20bd791130d6b6","Foto5":"2b24d495052a8ce66358eb576b8912c8"}}
02-21 12:02:58.894 809-809/com.mindfunk.rething D/extendedProfileRequest: Succeed ThingProfile2 decargado correctamente Thing =  com.mindfunk.rething.models.RethingThing@79e8c23
02-21 12:02:58.895 809-865/com.mindfunk.rething D/url: http://RETHING/IMAGES/7f1de29e6da19d22b51c68001e7e0e54.jpg
02-21 12:02:59.632 809-809/com.mindfunk.rething D/loaded conflictiveImage: loaded
02-21 12:02:59.734 809-809/com.mindfunk.rething D/layoutInfo: [20,20,991,700]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my mistake was using setLeft(), setTop(), setBottom(), and setRight() methods instead of setTranslationX() and setTranslationY().

I know we are supposed to read the whole documentation and it specifies first four methods can be called by layout system at any time, but why the h.. those methods are public then¿